# Passing a array value by ajax in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have done an ajax call by jQuery.ajax and tried like this

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: wpgiftstoreAjax.ajaxurl, 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                action: 'addgiftTocart',
                giftData: gdata,
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

I got the "gdata" by this

```
var gdata = JSON.stringify(GiftData);
```

But here I can't get the string data like this. I got a blank array. Just before the line, I have tried with this code and I got the array with data.

```
console.log(GiftData);
```

So I can't understand where is the problem with this. Please help me with this problem and thanks in advance.

My total code I have tried

```
    GiftData = [];
    GiftData['boxProduct'] = [];
    GiftData['boxName'] = jQuery('#giftbox-data .box-data').text();
    jQuery('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').each( function(i) {
        GiftData["boxProduct"][i] = [];
        GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['id'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-name').attr('prodid');
        GiftData['boxProduct'][i]['num'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-num').text();
    })
    GiftData['boxSenderInfo'] = jQuery('#giftbox-data .sender-info .gift-sender').text();
```

Comment: What si the result from ```var_dump($_REQUEST['giftData'])```?

Comment: It is showing NULL

Comment: Why you use it ```JSON.stringify()``` BTW? Send array directly?

Comment: I tried directly. it was also return blank.

Comment: Can you provide the entire code or web address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194763/discussion-between-ranjit-and-sky).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i have done in the above code is to have the square bracket"[" instead of "{".

This should be like this

```
    GiftData = {};
    GiftProdData = {};
    GiftData['boxProductData'] = {};
    GiftData['boxName'] = jQuery('#giftbox-data .box-data').text();
    jQuery('#giftbox-data .prod-data .product').each( function(i) {
        GiftData["boxProductData"][i] = {};
        GiftData['boxProductData'][i]['id'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-name').attr('prodid');
        GiftData['boxProductData'][i]['num'] = jQuery(this).find('.prod-num').text();
    })
```

Thank you for the cooperation.